# How to align html table td elements on the opposite (right) end of the screen

Tags: html, html-table

I have an image on the upper left of the screen but want to position some text on the evenly opposite side (upper right).  But this code positions the subsequent td elements only slightly to the right and a bit lower.  Do I need to add an align to the `<td>` elements?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="some_img" style='width:50%; height:50%;' />
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">t1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>t2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>t3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One closing `td` is missing, other than that you can use the `text-align` css property to align the items inside the cell.

If I understand correctly, you may want something like this:

```css
.cell{
  width: 50vw;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: right;
}

.image{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell image"><img src="some_img"/></td>
    <td class="cell">t1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell">t2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell"></td>
    <td class="cell">t3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's close to it!  But can t2 and t3 line up under t1?

Comment: Of course, just add the `cell` class to the other `td`s, I modified the answer.

Comment: Yes!  And to get rid of the gray background?

Comment: That's just a helper to see what's going on, simply remove the `background` prop from the `cell` class if you don't need it. Should I remove it from the answer?

Comment: The image tag shouldn't have the cell styling should it?  It text aligns left etc?

Comment: The `img` tag doesn't need the `cell` class to be aligned.

Comment: If t1 had to be a larger font size than the others could I put it inline or would it be overridden by the cell styling?

Comment: You can do it inline, the inline style overrides the styles in the class, but I suggest to create another class for that, it's more clear for later use.